# Nginx: Multiple PHP sites on different ports, on 1 server

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

newbie on web administration and was tasked to do the following:

- Migrate all web apps into 1 server with 1 public IP.
- Use NGINX as the web server.
- Use either the domain/IP while assigning the web apps on different
  port. e.g. web store for a client 204.XX.XX.XX:81, web admin tool for another client 204.XX.XX.XX:82 etc etc

Is this possible? Can this be achieved using virtual hosts? I'm asking this because most of our web apps are using the laravel framework. Please point me to the correct tuts.

Comment: Have you already had Nginx config?

Comment: yes I did, I tried sampling a single laravel web app and it is working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have not provided your config, the answer is very general:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  *.example.org;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       82;
    server_name  mail.*;
    ...
}

server {
    listen       83;
    server_name  ~^(?<user>.+)\.example\.net$;
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use domain, you can skip server_name.

**Articles for you:**

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Comment: Dont forget `root` ;-) but essentially this is what you'll need to do.

Comment: is it possible to use ip address instead of domain?

Comment: Yes it is possible. There are proper examples by links I wroted in my answer.